# MySQL Merge Two SELECT Queries With CASE On One Table

Tags: mysql, select, join, merge, union

I want to merge two queries into one full query. I would need the two queries to group on one aggregate field (MFG).  I would assume you use a `JOIN` but it is on the same table and with a `CASE` so I'm not sure how that could even work.

**1ST QUERY (2015)**

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%1%' THEN 'MFG1'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%2%' THEN 'MFG2'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%3%' THEN 'MFG3'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MFG,
    SUM(COST) AS Cost2015
FROM
    table
WHERE
    TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY MFG
```

**2ND QUERY (2014)**

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%1%' THEN 'MFG1'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%2%' THEN 'MFG2'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%3%' THEN 'MFG3'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MFG,
    SUM(COST) AS Cost2014
FROM
    table
WHERE
    TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY MFG
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
MFG  |  Cost2015  |  Cost2014
MFG1 |   1500     |     0
MFG2 |   1000     |    1200
MFG3 |     0      |    3600
     |    100     |     15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in `SUM()`

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%1%' THEN 'MFG1'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%2%' THEN 'MFG2'
        WHEN ITEM LIKE '%3%' THEN 'MFG3'
        ELSE ''
    END AS MFG,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-31' THEN COST ELSE 0 END) AS Cost2014,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2015-12-31' THEN COST ELSE 0 END) AS Cost2015
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-12-31'
GROUP BY MFG
```

Comment: Thank you, it appears to be working the first few I do, let me run some more tests before accepting.